# is it possible to get an awt image of barcode with text

Tags: java, image, itext, bufferedimage, itextpdf

is it possible to extend the createAwtImage of a barcode type to give the same output as createImageWithBarcode (i.e. including the text below), so that it can be written directly to an image rather than into a PDF?

At the moment I have to use barcode4j to do this but would much prefer to use iText. Or maybe I can take the `java.awt.Image`, add some extra space at the bottom and add text in this extra space. How can I do this?

edited:
groovy code to do this

```
 img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE)
 int w = barcode.getBarcodeSize().getWidth()*3
 int h = barcode.getBarcodeSize().getHeight()*3
 bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
 int fontSize = 20
 g2 = bi.createGraphics()
 g2.setColor(Color.WHITE)
 g2.fillRect(0,0,w,h)
 g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h-fontSize, null)
 g2.setFont(new Font('Arial', Font.PLAIN, fontSize))
 stringLen = g2.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(fm_content, g2).getWidth()
 start = w/2 - stringLen/2
 g2.setColor(Color.BLACK)
 g2.drawString(fm_content, start.toInteger(), h-2)
 g2.dispose()
 return bi
```

Comment: Good question (I don't understand the down-vote). You mention `createAwtImage()` which is indeed a method that only create the bar code *without* any text. iText doesn't add text to this AWT `Image`. However, you could use this image and add text using plain old Java code. The question could be rephrased as: "How can I extend the size of an image and add some text to this image in Java?" I am going to update the tags to reflect this.

Comment: The groovy code you have posted, is basically Java without semicolons at the end of each line... Any reason you can't use that? Or is the edit an answer to your own question? If so, you should post it as an answer (and earn some rep along the way). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer as per the code edit..
Fill the background, place the barcode over less than the vertical height and use setFont method of image - measure text width first and start it at half the distance between the image size and the text size.

```
 img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
 int w = barcode.getBarcodeSize().getWidth() * 3;
 int h = barcode.getBarcodeSize().getHeight() * 3;

 BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
 int fontSize = 20;

 Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
 g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
 g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h - fontSize, null);

 g2.setFont(new Font('Arial', Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
 double stringLen = g2.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(fm_content, g2).getWidth();
 double start = w / 2 - stringLen / 2;
 g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 g2.drawString(fm_content, (int) Math.round(start), h - 2);

 g2.dispose();

 return bi;
```